# If you accidentally drop your table where does the table structure go to?

Tags: sql, oracle

If you accidentally drop your table where does the table structure go to? So if I accidentally deleted a table where does the structure go?

Comment: Thanks for that great piece of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropping and deleting are not the same thing. Generally, when people say they deleted (or truncated) a table, they mean that they removed the rows from the table. When a table is dropped, the schema for that table, along with all data, associated indexes, etc, is erased. Without a backup to restore from you are out of luck.

Comment: Not necessarily true.  The table may be in the recycle bin.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping a table drops the table structure definition (since that's part of the table).

You do have a backup, right?

Answer (score 1):

The table structure is part of the table, so you can't really get rid of one without getting rid of the other.

So to answer the question, the structure gets launched into a black hole with the rest of the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running at least 9i version and if your dbms does not make a lot of transaction.
Hurry Up ! Digg into flashback area and recover it.
I think that also the standard SqlDeveloper tool should have a gui for such operation.

[Flashback 9i Howto](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/FlashbackQuery.php#ExampleDataRecovery)

If you are running 10g or 11g then you have optimal chances.

[Flashback 11g](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/FlashbackAndLogminerEnhancements_11gR1.php)

Comment: I agree "Not necessarily true. The table may be in the recycle bin." – jonearles